# How to get data only USD Rate from file_get_contents with PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

Please tell me how to get USD Data Rate only from this code?

(.*)/Ui',$data,$matches);
    $title = $matches[1];
    
    
    foreach ($title as $value) {
        echo $value. "";
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is the full Code

```
    <?php

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi');

preg_match_all('/<td.*>(.*)<\\/td>/Ui',$data,$matches);
$title = $matches[1];


foreach ($title as $value) {
    echo $value. "</br>";
}
```